# How to convert/format files back to programs,and other stuff?

Tags: windows-registry, database, file-conversion, file-unlocking

I dunno if this was asked (excuse me if yes), I did checked first 3 pages but nothing found so...

I have SSD (C:) and HDD(D:).I hided files and programs, with program HIDE FILES(by vovsoft) which was installed on my C: and I hided files that are on D:
Well I did gave a laptop for repair, and they reinstalled my Win10 which was on C: . I was okay with this, then I installed back that program HIDE FILES to unhide files on D:, but it didnt work, coz the program writes values to registry to hide the files(I realized that late), but the registry was reseted so...

Q:It is safe on D: it has 30GB.But I cannot use them.Is there some way to bring it back?

PS:I do not have neither restore point, nor backups of registry.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you may forget about these files.

Answer (score 1):

The [Hide Files FAQ](https://vovsoft.com/blog/hide-files-faq/) has this Q&A:

> Question: My computer crashed, i cannot access my hidden files. What
>   can I do?
>
> Your files are still on your hard disk. However their filenames and
>   directory structure was on Windows Registry. Hide Files can not
>   restore the files without Windows Registry entries. Please try
>   recovering your files using recovery software such as ZAR X, R-Studio,
>   GetDataBack, EaseUS, Recuva. Don't write anything else to the drive.
>   Save the recovered contents to another drive.

I understand from this that the files are still on the disk, but only their names
have been mangled. They don't seem to have been encrypted in any way.

I suggest using Explorer and enabling the showing of hidden files in
*View > Options > View tab*, check "Show hidden f‌iles, folders, and drives"
and click OK.

If you now see files with strange names in your folders,
you will need to identify them by their contents.
If the files are not in their original folders, you will need to search for
them.

Comment: Note: HIDE FILES seems to me to be a pretty lame protection.